# Django concat variable in template

Tags: django

i have this template on my Django

```
{% for car in cars%}
   <div class="form-row">
      <label for="detail-{{ detail.id }}"> <b>{{ detail.rejected_field.title }}</b> :
           <img id="car-image" src="{{ car_manager_image_ + car.id }}">
      </label>
  </div>
{%endfor%}
```

car_manager_image is another image url sent via extra_context['car_manager_image_'+car.id] on the backend

my question is, how do i concate the data on Django Template?

im expecting result like 'car_manager_image_1'

Answer (score 1):

You can use django build in [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter to concat both strings. Your code should be changed to

```
<img id="car-image" src="{{ car_manager_image_|add:car.id }}">
```

Comment: actually i tried this and it gives me (unkown)